# "the question has arisen more than once" "the question has been arising more than once"

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

Is it more correct to say **"the question has arisen more than once"** or **"the question has been arising more than once".**
Or maybe it's much better to say: *"the question arose"?*

Comment: Principal parts: arise, arose, arisen. Thanks. Michael

Answer (score 1):

The question has **arisen** more than once.
That is how the participle of *arise* is spelled.
Otherwise, the phrasing is correct.

*Has been arising more than once*
doesn't make sense.